# How to add "IF result = X" than "RETURN x" to this javascript code?

Tags: javascript, node.js

#### My Code:

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');

const crashHash = '';
// Hash from bitcoin block #610546. Public seed event: https://twitter.com/Roobet/status/1211800855223123968
const salt = '0000000000000000000fa3b65e43e4240d71762a5bf397d5304b2596d116859c';

function saltHash(hash) {
 return crypto
  .createHmac('sha256', hash)
  .update(salt)
  .digest('hex');
}

function generateHash(seed) {
 return crypto
  .createHash('sha256')
  .update(seed)
  .digest('hex');
}

function divisible(hash, mod) {
 // We will read in 4 hex at a time, but the first chunk might be a bit smaller
 // So ABCDEFGHIJ should be chunked like  AB CDEF GHIJ
 var val = 0;

 var o = hash.length % 4;
 for (var i = o > 0 ? o - 4 : 0; i < hash.length; i += 4) {
  val = ((val << 16) + parseInt(hash.substring(i, i + 4), 16)) % mod;
 }

 return val === 0;
}

function crashPointFromHash(serverSeed) {
 const hash = crypto
  .createHmac('sha256', serverSeed)
  .update(salt)
  .digest('hex');

 const hs = parseInt(100 / 4);
 if (divisible(hash, hs)) {
  return 1;
 }

 const h = parseInt(hash.slice(0, 52 / 4), 16);
 const e = Math.pow(2, 52);

 return Math.floor((100 * e - h) / (e - h)) / 100.0;
}

function getPreviousGames() {
 const previousGames = [];
 let gameHash = generateHash(crashHash);

 for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  const gameResult = crashPointFromHash(gameHash);
  previousGames.push({ gameHash, gameResult });
  gameHash = generateHash(gameHash);
 }

 return previousGames;
}

function verifyCrash() {
 const gameResult = crashPointFromHash(crashHash);
 const previousHundredGames = getPreviousGames();

 return { gameResult, previousHundredGames };
}

console.log(verifyCrash());
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crash-gl2qb?from-embed=&file=/src/index.js:0-1721)

---

I'm trying to make this code show the results it already shows, but I want it to add something to the end of each `gameResult` data so it would look like this: `gameResult: 4.39 "maybe"`

I've tried to add something like this to the code with no luck. I had it working to the point where it would only return the very first `gameResult` but not the ones after. If someone could help that would be great, or if you have another way other than this code below that I was trying to use, that works too.

```js
function gameResult
  const result =
    if (gameResult === 1) {
      return "no";
    };
    if (gameResult <= 3) {
      return "maybe";
    };
    if (gameResult <= 10) {
      return "yes";
    };
```

Comment: Java has nothing to do with JavaScript

Comment: There are a few syntax errors here that should be fixed first.  The function definition is incomplete, and `return` exits a function.  It does not return a value to a variable assignment.

Comment: If you want to do the tests in the assignment, you need to use the conditional operator `condition ? true-valiue : false-value`, not `if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I understand correctly the expected output should be like this,

```
{
    "gameResult": "4.39 "yes"",
    "previousHundredGames": [...]
}
```

I am able to do this by modifying the `verifyCrash` function to this,

```
function verifyCrash() {
  let gameResult = crashPointFromHash(crashHash);
  const previousHundredGames = getPreviousGames();
  if (gameResult === 1) {
    gameResult=+' "no"';
  }
  if (gameResult <= 3) {
    gameResult=+' "maybe"';
  }
  if (gameResult <= 10) {
    gameResult+= ' "yes"';
  }
  return { gameResult, previousHundredGames };
}
```

Check this link to see it in action,
https://codesandbox.io/s/crash-forked-f7fb7

Comment: THANK you sir you are awesome probably fastest answer ive ever gotten lol. OK I have one more question for you well maybe 2. I want to change the math to this code to another games math here is the link to a forum showing the games code https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=2807542.0 
So i want to take the math from that link and input it into the sandboxes code.

Comment: Ok so i just checked the rest of the console results and only the very first game result shows yes the others dont show a yes no or maybe after the gameResult number.

Also my last question is how would I make it show starting from the bottom and working backwards how would I show the gameResults to say IF gameResult from previous game is >= current gameResult return UP and IF gameResult from previous game is <= current gameResult return DOWN. So basically it would look kinda like this

gameResult; 5.46 "UP"
gameResult: 4.44 "DOWN
gameResult 21.26 "UP
gameResult: 2 "DOWN
gameResult: 5

Comment: @exitends I edited the code to add yes, maybe and no for the elements in the previousHundredGames array too

Comment: Awesome ive been tryin to get that to work for a few days now thank you! Any luck with the other 2 questions? Is my 3rd question even possible to do?